# Questions about algebraic curve definition

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The algebraic curve definition states as following

$S_{2}^m$ denotes homogeneous polynomial of degree $m$ in $x$ and $y$

$f_{m}(x, y) = \sum_{j, k \ge 0, j+k=m} C_{j,k}x^{j}y^{k}$

The elements of $f \in S_{2}^m$ have the property of $\alpha^{m}f(x,y) =  f(\alpha x, \alpha y )$

I'm just wondering why the $f_{m}(x, y)$ does't include some terms: 
e.g. $ax \text{ or } by$

In other word, $S_{2}^{m}$ does't include the term of the sum of the power of x and y is not equal to m

Comment: The definition seems unambiguous, so I'm assuming you want motivation. You're trying to cut something out on $\mathbf P^1$. The vanishing of something like $2x + xy$ depends on the representative, e.g., plug in $(1,-2)$ and $(2,-4)$.

Comment: @bsdshell: To clarify, are you asking 1. Why does a homogeneous polynomial contain only monomials of the some fixed degree? 2. Why must we use homogeneous polynomials to cut out a plane curve in projective space? or 3. Something else?

Comment: Why does a homogeneous polynomial contain only monomials of the some fixed degree?

Comment: What is your definition of homogeneous? For an algebraist I think the definition usually is that it only has monomials of a fixed degree. If your starting definition is "$f(x, y)$ is homogeneous of degree $d$ if $f(ax,ay) = a^df(x,y)$ for all $a \in k$ the base field" then yes, you need to make a short argument [$k$ should probably be infinite]. Is this what you want? It's not at all clear from the question.

Comment: Let's try the degree of polynomial is 2 in x and y, then we knew from secondary school, we have  $f(x, y) = ax^{2} + by^{2} + cxy + dx + ey + f  = 0$, this is general polynomial we lean in secondary school. But the algebraic curve definition ignore the term $dx, ey$

Comment: Does my first comment make sense to you?

Comment: yep, Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Proj}{\mathbf{P}}$Let $k$ be a positive integer. A monomial $f$ of degree $k$ in two variables satisfies the homogeneity conditon $f(ax, ay) = a^{k} f(x, y)$ (for all non-zero $a$) by elementary algebra. It's not difficult to see that a sum of monomials of different degrees is not homogeneous at all. Consequently if a polynomial $f$ in two variables is homogeneous of degree $m$, then $f$ is a sum of monomials of degree (precisely) $m$.

**Added in edit**: The preceding paragraph is mathematically correct, but at least partially misses the point of the question (i.e., doesn't fully address the issues mentioned in the comments).

Points in the projective plane $\Proj^{2}$ (i.e., lines through the origin in three-dimensional space) are described by *triples* (not pairs) of homogeneous coordinates $[X : Y : Z]$. (If $a \neq 0$, then $[X : Y : Z] = [aX : aY : aZ]$ as points in the projective plane. Consequently, the homogeneous coordinates $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ aren't "coordinates" (scalar-valued functions) in $\Proj^{2}$ in the sense of elementary geometry; only their *ratios* $x = X/Z$, $y = Y/Z$, etc. are well-defined numerical functions.)

If $F$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $m > 0$ (in *three* variables), in the sense that
$$
F(aX, aY, aZ) = a^{m} F(X, Y, Z)\quad\text{for all $a$,}
$$
then $F$ is not a well-defined scalar-valued function on $\Proj^{2}$. Despite this, the condition $F(X, Y, Z) = 0$ *is* well-defined on $\Proj^{2}$. (Why?) The locus
$$
\bigl\{[X : Y : Z] \in \Proj^{2} : F(X, Y, Z) = 0\bigr\}
$$
is the *plane curve* cut out by $F$. (Exercise: If $F$ is a non-homogeneous polynomial in three variables, the condition $F(X, Y, Z) = 0$ is *not* well-defined on $\Proj^{2}$.)

To see the relationship with the definition from secondary school, write the general homogeneous polynomial of degree $m$ as
$$
F(X, Y, Z) = \sum_{\substack{j, k, \ell \geq 0 \\ j + k + \ell = m}} C_{jk\ell}\; X^{j} Y^{k} Z^{\ell}.
$$
In $\bigl\{[X : Y : Z] : Z \neq 0\bigr\}$ (a well-defined subset of $\Proj^{2}$), introduce the "affine coordinates" $x = X/Z$ and $y = Y/Z$. Dividing $F(X, Y, Z)$ by $Z^{m}$ gives the *non-homogeneous* polynomial
$$
f(x, y) = \sum_{\substack{j, k, \ell \geq 0 \\ j + k + \ell = m}} C_{jk\ell}\; x^{j} y^{k}.
$$
Formally, set $Z = 1$, replace $X$ with $x$, and replace $Y$ with $y$. Because $x$ and $y$ are well-defined numerical coordinates on the *affine chart* $\{Z \neq 0\}$, the polynomial $f$ has a well-defined zero locus, the "finite part" of the projective curve $\{F = 0\}$ with respect to the affine chart $\{Z \neq 0\}$. (In this chart, $\{Z = 0\}$ is the *line at infinity*.)

This process can be inverted. For example, the general inhomogeneous quadratic
$$
f(x, y) = ax^{2} + bxy + cy^{2} + dx + ey + f
$$
is "homogenized" by replacing $x$ with $X$ and $y$ with $Y$, then multiplying each monomial of degree $2 - \ell$ by $Z^{\ell}$:
$$
F(X, Y, Z) = aX^{2} + bXY + cY^{2} + dXZ + eYZ + fZ^{2}.
$$

The diagram (a frame from an [animation of a rotating cone](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/teach13/392/rotating_cone.gif)) shows the circle $x^{2} + y^{2} - 1 = 0$ in the plane $\{Z = 1\}$ (the red grid) represented as the projective conic cut out by the homogeneous equation
$$
(X\cos\theta - Z\sin\theta)^{2} + Y^{2} - (Z\cos\theta + X\sin\theta)^{2} = 0,
$$
i.e., by $X^{2} + Y^{2} - Z^{2} = 0$ when $\theta = 0$.

[image: A circle represented as a conic section]